# Dados de um arquivo .Json

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets

Eai galera, tudo bem? ... Eu estou tendo um problema onde eu preciso pegar um bloco de dados de um arquivo json, sendo ele:

```
{
        "custom_fields": {
            "[TS] A empresa em que você trabalha é": "uma fábrica/indústria",
            "[TS] Setor da empresa": "Outros",
            "[TS] Compra de Lubrificante": "Sim - acima de 2.000 litros",
            "[TS] Função na empresa": "Técnico",
            "[TS] Departamento da empresa": "Administração",
            "[TS] Site": "SCP"
        }
}
```

Eu estou tento um grande problema para pegar os dados onde tem colchete e espaço, pois sempre dá o erro: **SyntaxError: Unexpected token [**

```
var JSONSource = JSON.stringify(requestData);

  //Extrai dados do lead para inserção
  for (var i = 0; i < leadData.length; i++) {
    values.push([
                 JSONSource,
                 leadData[i].custom_fields.[TS] A empresa em que você trabalha é,
                 leadData[i].custom_fields.[TS] Setor da empresa,
                 leadData[i].[TS] Compra de Lubrificante,
                 leadData[i].[TS] Departamento da empresa,
                 leadData[i].[TS] Site
                ]);
  }
```

Por fim, eu queria saber como faço pra pegar esses mesmo dados com essa formatação, sendo que essa formatação/estrutura está vindo de uma API, então eu não posso mudar a chave dela.

Outra coisa é que eu to fazendo isso no script do google sheets, que usa o mesmo motor do Js, mas com suas peculiaridades, estou com certa dificuldade pois não tenho quase nenhum conhecimento nesse tipo de script.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda de vocês!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conhecendo as chaves, tente acessar como um array. Veja abaixo:

```
leadData[i].custom_fields["[TS] A empresa em que você trabalha é"];
```

É necessário acessar desta forma porque as chaves são irregulares (possuem espaço, acentos, etc). Caso exista alguma chave que é apenas uma palavra, sem caracteres especiais, você vai conseguir acessar com ponto `leadData[i].custom_fields.exemplo1`.

Abraços

Comment: Obrigado Tiago, consegui aqui. Mas meu amigo, porque raios eu consigo acessar alguns dados leadData[i].custom_fields.exemplo1 e nesse não, sendo que ambos tem a mesma estrutura?

Comment: @MoisesFausto incrementei a resposta com essa sua dúvida.